# Is there any way to pass parameter of @Body instead of multiple @Field

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, httpresponse

I have a backend server and want to make a Http POST call with a Body Parameter.

I create a Post request having @Header with api key and @Body with user info. But when I hit the api, in response it shows a response like this "data":[] where it should be like "data":{}. But if I send multiple @Field as parameter, it will be okey. Is there any process to use @Body instead of multiple @Field

`SignInInfo.kt`

```
data class SignInInfo(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("user_type") val userType: String,
    @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("password") val password: String
)
```

`api.kt`

```
@POST(Constants.API_USER_REGISTRATION)
fun registerUser(
    @Body signInInfo: SignInInfo
): Call<RegistrationResponse>
```

`api.kt`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Constants.API_USER_REGISTRATION)
fun registerUser(
    @Field("name") name: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("user_type") user_type: String,
    @Field("phone") phone: String,
    @Field("password") password: String
): Call<RegistrationResponse>
```

I got this expected answer while use @Field parameter

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "id": 135386,
        "user_id": 1567057386,
        "token": "geYs2rO6wjtO653I9OVhJWTFwYxAvnYnLGG7wm7dfa"
    },
    "msg": "Welcome Aomi"
}
```

I got this unexpected answer while use @Body parameter

```
{
    "status": 2,
    "data": [],
    "msg": "Failed"
}
```

Comment: you have done in a right way can you share api ink

Answer (score 1):

Your Body data class should look like this

```
data class Body(
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: Int? = 0,
    @SerializedName("data")
    val `data`: Data? = Data(),
    @SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String? = ""
)

data class Data(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int? = 0,
        @SerializedName("user_id")
        val userId: Int? = 0,
        @SerializedName("token")
        val token: String? = ""
)
```

if you want to get this kind of json

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "id": 135386,
        "user_id": 1567057386,
        "token": "geYs2rO6wjtO653I9OVhJWTFwYxAvnYnLGG7wm7dfa"
    },
    "msg": "Welcome Aomi"
```

and usage

```
@POST(Constants.API_USER_REGISTRATION)
fun registerUser(
    @Body signInInfo: Body
): Call<RegistrationResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this like this

```
    @POST(Constants.API_USER_REGISTRATION)
    fun generateOTPForgotPassword(@Body signInInfo: SignInInfo): Call< RegistrationResponse>
```

Just like the way you did.